# Styling a specific image in Cargo

Tags: cargo-collective

I am working on a site in cargo and need to place an image that doesn't share the same styling needs as the others. I have all other images styled to have a border on them in the img tag in CSS, so I thought I could put a class or ID tag and just have `"border: none;"` and it would remove the styling from the image. This doesn't seem to be working. I don't know if i need to just style the images with a class instead of the img tag, which would be frustrating to change.

```
<div id="blankimage" grid-col="5" grid-pad="1.5" class="" img="">
    {image 22}
</div>
```

is what I have. I tried a class too just to see if maybe it just didn't like the ID tag but that didn't work (hence the empty class tag). It shows up with the border still on the image. any time i try to style an image tag like this:

```
<img style="border:none;" src= {image 22} >
```

this doesn't seem to work either and Cargo will remove it out of my code. I don't know if i am missing something or if it is cargo, but it is probably me.

Comment: *"this doesn't seem to work either and Cargo will remove it out of my code"* perhaps you just need to close the tag properly e.g. with `/>` ?

Comment: I double checked that as well, didn't work :(

Comment: ... and did you try to close with `</img>` ?